# How to skip tab scenes getting pushed into the navigation history stack in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a `<Tab>` element and there are some sub scenes under it. It when I navigate to the page consisting tabs and go to different tabs or not at the end when i press back button (which is `Actions.pop()` and i have a custom navbar) it always jumps to first tab. then again i have to press back to actually get out of the tab view.

What props or techniques i can use to that it does not jumps to first tab and actually leave the tab view page?

Comment: You probably need to keep the `backBehavior` as `none`. it defaults to `initialRoute`. Check [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html)

Comment: @Ejaz that was the solution. Thanks. if you post an answer then I can accept it as the right answer.